# Получение текущих GPS координат

Tags: android, java, gps

Как запросить текущие GPS координаты устройства? Я видел функцию getLasKnownLocation но ее название и применение говорит само за себя. Требуется получать (запрашивать у модуля) текущую локацию телефона

Comment: Вот отличная статья http://habrahabr.ru/post/122705/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
public class MyLocationActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener 
{
    private static final String TAG=MyLocationActivity.class.getName();

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
    {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.main);
       LocationManager lm =
              (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
       lm.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
    {
       if (location != null) 
       {
          Log.d(TAG, "Широта="+location.getLatitude());
          Log.d(TAG, "Долгота="+location.getLongitude());
       }
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) 
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) 
    {
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) 
    {
    }
}
```

Только надо озаботиться соотвествующими пермишеном в манифесте

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
```