# Не работает получение координат через GPS

Tags: java, android, gps

Пытался [этим методом](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/74344/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%89%D0%B8%D1%85-gps-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%82) и статьи из хабра (такой же код), в обоих случаях тестировал на эмуляторе genymotion, там все прекрасно работает, но запустил на своём девайсе "билайн смарт 3" и координаты не получаются (хотя иконка есть). В чем может быть проблема? (кидает NullPointerExecption тк координаты не появились)

Comment: У вас там, случаем, не 6 версия ОС стоит?..

Comment: На девайсе Android 4.4.2, на эмуляторе тоже 4.2.2 (htc one x)

Comment: Я лично с координатами не работал, но, может быть, дело в долгом запуске GPS датчика... Может, если вы будете отлавливать ошибку, то через n времени координаты пойдут. Ещё, может, не включено на девайсе/эмуляторе в настройках координат получение.

Comment: На эмуляторе работает, на девайсе нет :) (в настройках пишет то что приложение использует GPS) Я подозреваю то что надо проверять разрешение тк он пишет надо добавить "Add premission check", думаю надо будет сделать все по этой статьи https://habrahabr.ru/post/278945/ и все заработает.

Comment: Да, такой способ получения разрешений должен помочь хотя, кмк, он должен требоваться только с 6 версии ОС. Но, может, оно сделано иначе в новых версиях либ или зависит от targetSDK. Попробуйте его понизить до 21, например.

Comment: Я понизил до 22, необходимости в "Add premission check" пропала, на эмуляторе опять же работает, а на девайсе нет

Comment: Ну... Тогда у меня нет других мыслей кроме как в рантайме попробовать разрешение запросить(